# ASP.NET 1.1 - "<%=" and "%>" tags being rendered in address bar

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-1.1

I inherited an ASP.NET 1.1 application that was written about 8 years ago, the app is obviously someone's first immersion in .NET as the code is a mixture of code-behind as well as server-side scattered throughout the markup.

The problem I'm having is that the form label has an action that looks like this:

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" action="?id=<%= fooId %>" runat="server">
```

When the save button is hovered over I see in the status bar:

```
?id=<%= fooId %>
```

As opposed to:

```
?id=123
```

If the user clicks the save button, the address bar shows:

```
http://servername/virtdir/pagename.aspx?id=<%= fooid %>
```

Which obviously causes the application to throw an exception.  I've tried using:

```
action="?id=<% Response.Write(fooId) %>"
```

But still get the same problem.  The problem is localized to this page, what else can I try?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put <%= into a runat=server tag - your telling it to break into server side code when it already is.  Try setting the action programatically in the codebehind.

Comment: I should have put <% %> instead of <%= really - you cant use any of that kind of thing when you have runat=server.

Comment: <beating head on desk>Jeez ... you would have thought all the years I've developed ASP.NET would have taught me to look at this</beating head on desk>